# Javascript does not run after aspx page has been loaded

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

I created a site in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition starting with the ASP.NET Empty Web Site template.  Recently, I needed to add authentication features, so I created a new ASP.NET Web Forms site, and moved all of my pages/files/entire site created in the empty web site to this new Web Forms site template.

Everything works perfectly--except that none of the javascript that used to update my pages dynamically continue to work.  All of the javascript functions that previously worked seem to be completely ignored.  (I haven't changed anything in the HTML or Javascript code -- the only thing that changed was the ASP.NET template I began with).  Even something as simple as tagging the navigation menu to be active will not work, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            // this will get the full URL at the address bar
            var url = window.location.href;

            // passes on every "a" tag
            $(".Navigation a").each(function() {
                // checks if its the same on the address bar
                if (url == (this.href)) {
                    $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
                }
            });
        });        
    </script>
```

This worked perfectly to highlight the active menu previously, but no longer works in the new Web Forms site template.  I've also tried moving it from the file header, to the content, and even to a separately referenced file with no avail.

Is there an assembly I need to add to my new project, or is there a global setting in this ASP.NET Web Forms template that could be blocking my javascript from working?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've been stuck on this problem for over a week now.

Edit:  here's a better example to see if I'm missing something more obvious:
This worked previously to dynamically load more information from a database after a page was loaded and the user scrolled to the bottom.  The javascript still works to display a message box when the user hits the bottom of the page, but the Web Method in the c# code behind never gets called...

```
    var pageIndex = 1;
    var pageCount;
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        // Everytime that the user scroll reaches the bottom of the page, execute function GetRecords
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            GetRecords();
        }
    });
    function GetRecords() {
        // Local variable page index begins at 1, and each time the user scrolls to the bottom of the page
        // this number is increased to mark how many times the user has hit the bottom of the page.
        // This later marks how many elements have been loaded from the database.
        pageIndex++;

        // On first scroll, pageCount is null so pageIndex is 2, and function still needs to be executed.
        if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {

            // Display a loading bar
            $("#loader").show();
            window.alert("loading");
            $.ajax({
                // POST signals a data request
                type: "POST",
                // This directs which function in the c# code behind to use
                url: "databaseLoadDynamic.aspx/GetCustomers",
                // The paramater pageIndex, page number we need to load, to pass to GetCustomers(int pageIndex)
                data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                // Type of data we are sending to the server (i.e. the pageIndex paramater)
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                // Type of data we expect back from the server (to fill into the html ultimately)
                dataType: "json",
                // If all goes smoothly to here, run the function that fills our html table
                success: OnSuccess,
                // On failure, error alert user (aka me so that I know something isn't working)
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: Did you add jQuery?

Comment: I have jQuery files in a js folder that I reference in the header...they're the same ones as I had before too

Comment: Is there another place that I need to add jQuery?

Comment: No that should work. Try adding a random alert in this .ready function. I had my share of problems using .ready with web forms.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: yeah, there's no console errors

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I just added an alert box, and it popped up, so maybe there is a problem with my javascript.  thanks I never thought to do that

Comment: did you change from flat html to aspx?  if so you may need to change your html attributes to use cssclass instead of class if they are runat server.  Have you checked the source to make sure the elements you are targeting are still under the same selectors?

Comment: You should [debug your javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp). This link contains the how to do for each of the most popular browsers.

Comment: @Pete the previous site was aspx also, so none of the attributes changed there.  same with the selectors, I kept them with the same names

Comment: Have you got a staging server where we can see the site?

Comment: @Pete thank you so much for all of your help, I just added an edit with a more complex function.  I was wrong, the javascript seems to be working now, but when I get to a point to call a Web Method in the code behind, it doesn't work...is there something I need to add for ajax to work?

Comment: I reference the javascript file from this link http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js, and have also saved it in my website in case it was something external for the .ajax part of the method to work

Comment: Been a while since I did aspx but I seem to remember when I did an ajax call I had to create a handler (ashx file) to do the processing and point my ajax call at that - there may be a new way to do it now as it has been 5 years since my last webforms project

Comment: @Pete I had no idea about this, I do a lot of ajax calls so this could definitely be the problem.  Would you be able to send a link on how to create a handler possibly?  I've never done that before.  Thanks so much again seriously

Comment: You could see if an [update panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx) will do the job for you, but here is an intro to [Handlers](https://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx)

Comment: @Pete thank you!!! I think this should do the trick